# What does the toolbox do?

Tags: world-of-tanks-blitz

The toolbox claims to give *"+25% to repair speed"*, but there doesn't appear to any need to repair your tanks; there is no way to repair the whilst in a game (as far as I know), and they are automatically repaired to full health instantly when you return to your garage.

[image: The equipment screen]

Does it have any use? Or does it just make your tank heavier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can repair during battle, and that repairing goes faster (25%, but you had that figured out). From [here](http://wiki.worldoftanks.com/Battle_Mechanics#Repair)

> If you take module damage during battle, your crew will instantly start repairing it by restoring a specific amount of hitpoints to the module every second. The actual amount that gets repaired every second depends on the specific module itself (not just its type) and the effective repair skill of your crew.
>
> Your crew will only repair a damaged module just enough to make it operational again, i.e. it will remain in "yellow" or damaged state. The exact amount of hitpoints this state represents depends on the specific module as well.
>
> To get a module fully operational again and restore all of its hitpoints to it during battle you must use a consumable. The Small Repair Kit is bought for credits and allows you to repair one module during the battle (starting from patch 0.7.4 both tracks can be repaired at once if they are both damaged). The Large Repair Kit costs either gold, or, starting from patch 085, credits, and fully repairs all modules that are damaged at the time you use it. It will also provide a bonus of 10% to the crew's repair speed unless consumed.

I believe it is a good thing you never needed to repair anything in battle ;). So if you never needed it, it would be a waste of money and weight.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to accept this ages ago.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the toolbox is used to accelerate repairing damaged modules during fight (modules getting "yellow" or "red". It will have the same functionality here..

on worldoftanks.eu it says:

> PRECISE MECHANICS – penetration zones, sniper mode, losing your tracks
>   and targeting enemy modules.
>   [source](http://worldoftanks.eu/en/news/pc-browser/46/blitz-release-announcement/)

Comment: I'm not sure  what you mean by this "Precise Mechanics" bit.

Comment: @peper757 I took this from the site. it's a game-feature.